# Searching line by line text between first two matches

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep, sed, awk

I have the file with text:

```
1861_ASSET-D_T_201702181000-201702181045_HN_
197895_STRING-H_T_201702181000-201702181045_HN_
14512861_FILE-FD_T_201702181000-201702181045_HN
```

How I can allocate text between first and second matches "_" using egrep, awk or sed?

I want to have:

```
ASSET-D
STRING-H
FILE-FD
```

Comment: Only those three languages? If so, why?

Answer (score 10):

You can use `awk` with the following parameters:

- `-F "_"`  - which uses `_` as separator
- `'{print $2}'` - which prints the 2nd element

  ```
  $ awk -F  "_" '{print $2}' input_file
  ASSET-D
  STRING-H
  FILE-FD
  ```

Answer (score 10):

```
$ sed -r 's/[^_]+_([^_]+)_.*/\1/' file
ASSET-D
STRING-H
FILE-FD
```

#### Explanation

- `-r` Use ERE
- `s/old/new/` replace `old` with `new`
- `[^_]+` some characters that are not underscore
- `(some chars)` save `some chars` for later
- `.*` any number of any characters
- `\1` the saved pattern

Answer (score 9):

If you want to allow other tools, `cut` would be the most simple solution:

```
cut -d _ -f 2 < input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

A couple of perl approaches:

```
$ perl -F_ -lae 'print $F[1]' file 
ASSET-D
STRING-H
FILE-FD
```

The `-a` makes perl act like awk, splitting each input line on the character given by `-F` and saving each resulting field in the array `@F`. Therefore, printing `$F[1]` will print the 2nd field (arrays start counting at 0).

Alternatively:

```
$ perl -pe 's/.*?_(.+?)_.*/$1/' file 
ASSET-D
STRING-H
FILE-FD
```

The `-p` means "print every input line after running the script given by `-e` on it". The `s/from/to/` is the substitution operator. It will replace `from` with `to`. Here, I am matching 0 or more characters (`.*`) but making it "non-greedy" (`.*?`); that `?` makes it stop at the shortest possible match. Therefore, `.*?_` will match everything up to the 1st `_`. The next part, `(.+?)_` matches one or more characters until the next `_` and then we match everything else until the end of the line (`.*`). The parentheses "capture" the match, and make it available in the replacement side of the operator as `$1`. Therefore, the whole thing will just replace the entire line with whatever was inside the parentheses.

---

You could also just do this with `grep`:

```
$ grep -oP '^.*?_\K[^_]+' file 
ASSET-D
STRING-H
FILE-FD
```

The `-o` means "print only the part of each line that matched" and the `-P` turns on Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE) which give us `\K`. The `\K`, in turn, means "ignore everything matched until this point". This means that we can use the `^.*?_` to matche everything until the first `_` and then use `\K` to discard it so it isn't printed. Then, we just need as many non-`_` characters as we can find (`[^_]+`).

Answer (score 6):

As a python one- liner:

```
python3 -c "[print(l.split('_')[1]) for l in open('f')]"
```

where `'f'` is your file, in quotes, e.g.:

```
python3 -c "[print(l.split('_')[1]) for l in open('/home/jacob/blub')]"

ASSET-D
STRING-H
FILE-FD
```

#### Explanation

```
for l in open('f')
```

reads f *per line*, and

```
l.split('_')[1]
```

splits the line by the delimiter `_`, keeps the second string (index `[1]`, where `[0]` is the first.

```
print(l.split('_')[1])
```

subsequently prints the found string.

Comment: If you like functional style but don't want to abuse list comprehensions in Python: `import sys, operator, functools; print(*map(operator.itemgetter(1), map(functools.partial(str.split, sep="_"), sys.stdin)), sep="\n")` ;-]